# BsonDocument Serialized?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I wonder how the `BsonDocument` is implemented because I haven't been able to find any documentation about the implementation detail (https://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_BsonDocument.html

Does the `BsonDocument` just act as a wrapper around the binary data? Or does it serialize the retrieved BSON data into objects?

I'm asking because I want to forward the retrieved data from Mongo via a REST interface which exposes the data as BSON. If the C# driver serializes the retrieved BSON data it can't be a solution because of the serialization overhead. In other words, I want to avoid the serialization and forward the BSON data directly.

Comment: Does downvoter care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the `RawBsonDocument` type which acts as a wrapper around the binary data which solve my problem :)

> An immutable BSON document that is represented using only the raw bytes.